# Surrounding div tag does not apply background-color

Tags: css

The code goes:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I apply a `background-color` to wrapper, but it does not show unless I set a fixed height. Why does it do that considering content and sidebar are filling wrapper? What other ways are there to get the `background-color` to appear without setting a fixed height?

Comment: Is #content and #sidebar floated? Set #wrapper to `overflow:hidden;`.

Comment: Can we see the code/css that applies background-color to wrapper.

Comment: Yes, please show us the CSS for #wrapper, #content and #sidebar.

Comment: Marwelln, yes they are floated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone said in the comments, if their were floated (which they are), then apply `overflow: hidden` (which worked).

Answer (score 0):

> What other ways are there to get the
>   background-color to appear without
>   setting a fixed height?

- Float `#wrapper`
- Use a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best).
- Make sure you have content :)
- Make sure  `#wrapper` is `display:block` or `inline-block`
- Add padding

One way to check, besides [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), is set `border:1px solid red`, and see if you get a 2px line or if you see the border as you would expect. If you see the normal border, there is another problem: time to post your CSS.

Here's a quick-and-dirty clearfix you can try for now, see if this helps:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar -->
  </div>
  <br style="display:block;clear:both;width:100%" />
</div>
```